# Gstreamer receive video: streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)

Tags: c, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I'm trying to transmit RTP video stream through network via UDP protocol.

Here is pipeline code on sender side:

https://gist.github.com/mgalushka/68d8ee034849a7db4f1f234e73a41405

I can receive and see actual video if I run receiver with `gst-launch-1.0` command-line like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=1234 caps="application/x-rtp" ! rtph263pdepay ! avdec_h263 ! autovideosink
```

But I cannot see window with video when I execute receiver for same pipeline in **c** code.
Here is pipeline code on receiver side (in full - because I believe here is error somewhere):

```
void  _receive_video_init_gstreamer(NiceAgent *magent, guint stream_id, CustomData *data)
{
  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *capsfilter, *videoconvert, *h263p, *rtph263pdepay, *sink;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;
  GSource *bus_source;

  source = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsrc", "source");
  rtph263pdepay = gst_element_factory_make ("rtph263pdepay", "rtph263pdepay");
  h263p = gst_element_factory_make ("avdec_h263p", "h263p");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");

  g_object_set (source, "address", "127.0.0.1", NULL);
  g_object_set (source, "port", 1234, NULL);

  g_object_set (source, "caps", gst_caps_from_string("application/x-rtp"), NULL);

  g_object_set (sink, "sync", FALSE, NULL);

  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("Video receive pipeline");

  if (!pipeline || !source ||
      !h263p || !rtph263pdepay || !sink)
  {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return;
  }

  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source,
            rtph263pdepay, h263p, sink, NULL);

  if (gst_element_link_many (source,
                rtph263pdepay, h263p, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
    g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return;
  }

  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  gst_bus_enable_sync_message_emission (bus);
  gst_bus_add_signal_watch (bus);

  g_signal_connect (bus, "message::error",
      (GCallback) on_error, NULL);

  data->pipeline = pipeline;
  ret = gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return;
  }
}
```

Error onserved from code:

```
WARN    basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2943:void gst_base_src_loop(GstPad *):<source> error: Internal data flow error. 
WARN    basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2943:void gst_base_src_loop(GstPad *):<source> error: streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4) 
ERROR   default gstreamer_utils.c:42:on_error: Error received from element source: Internal data flow error.
```

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: two things come up to my mind - you have additional `sync=false` in comparison to your launch pipe, the second one .. additionally try setting GST_STATE_PLAYING alson on sink element (but its not very good advice, just a shot in the dark) .. you may beed to debug your solution by either exporting or running with `GST_DEBUG=4 ./yourapp` .. then update the question or find out whats happening during link time (you get "not negotiated" which means the emenents could not be linked at runtime)

Comment: Thanks, @otopolsky I've run this without sync=false and GST_DEBUG=4, got some logs: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/99a9c4912f1970eb1c0e04967f03e286

Any idea where to look for the clues?

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same warning while building a RTP H264 pipe and could fix it.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5004 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,encoding-name=(string)H264,payload=(int)96" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Everything went well with gst-launch but in C it didn't started the stream.

I had the same warnings in the log file and and searched for the reason of "not-negotiated".

It turned out, that my **caps** configuration was wrong/incomplete. Gstreamer accecpts everything and doesn't complain until you see the "not-negotiated" message.

You should double check that all your elements are configured correct.
I had to compare the gst-launch and the application log messages to find the solution.

Btw. this was my test source stream and I work with windows, gstreamer version 1.14.4

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,framerate=20/1 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5004
```

Comment: Thanks for also including your source stream as well! I've been stuck for a some time and tried a number of examples; this is the first that was working for me right away on windows!

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for comment - its not answer but how to analyse:

Try making dot files to spot the differences.. I noticed in logs that there is opengl stuff involved - do you need that? Try changing autovideosink to something that is not using opengl.. not sure what options do you have on Mac (I hope I guessed it correctly) - on Linux I use ximagesink or xvimagesink.. on Mac there is osxvideosink (not sure if its build by default) - you can check [this](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+16%3A+Platform-specific+elements) ..

My guess of why is it behaving differently in gst-launch and your app is that you have some additional overhead in your app which causes the processing to be slowed or something and you get the not negotiated error as something is postponed..

I noticed this in logs:

> 0:00:00.608577000 29168 0x7fb5a401d850 INFO                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2838:void gst_base_src_loop(GstPad *): marking pending DISCONT

which means that some packets came later than expected and were discarded..

Try adding queues after udpsrc which will buffer few packets:

```
queue = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "srcqueue");
```

and of course add to pipe and link between:

```
if (gst_element_link_many (source, queue
            rtph263pdepay, h263p, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
```